# Laravel Queue: How to use on shared hosting

Tags: ssh, laravel-4

I have read tutorials on Laravel Queue using  `Beanstalkd` etc and the idea of using queue is fantastic because in my current project, sending a `Welcome` mail to a registered user takes up to 10 seconds to process cause of the attachment of a logo. I can imagine what will happen if more users register at an instance. So, using a queue for this will speed up things.

In the shared server I am working on, I have no `SSH Access`. So, setting up the queue according to the tutorials is far fetched.

I want to know if there is a way to setup Laravel Queue without `SSH Access`, if there is a way, I need a guide.

Comment: Not really. Just use Laravel Forge and migrate to a new server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `Beanstalkd` on a shared server because you can't install the service and I don't know any hosting service that offers it for shared hosting. However you could use [IronMQ](http://www.iron.io/mq) which is a remotely hosted service (so you don't need to install anything on the server). The Laravel queues API is the same for any queue service, so you can just use `Queue::push` like you would with `beanstalkd`.

Here's a great video on setting this up by Taylor Otwell, the creator of Laravel:
http://vimeo.com/64703617. You can also read this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/ironmq-laravel-setup/) which explains how to use IronMQ with Laravel in more detail.

IronMQ is a paid service<strike>, but it does have a [Free Plan](http://www.iron.io/pricing) for developers which offers 1 million API requests per month.</strike>

Instead of using `artisan queue:listen` like you would for `beanstalkd`, you just define a route for IronMQ to call when processing each job on the queue:

```
Route::post('queue/receive', function()
{
    return Queue::marshal();
});
```

Comment: Does that mean I won't need to `listen to queues`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You just push the queues to IronMQ and it will take care of the queue processing. I've updated my answer with a small explanation. It's very well explained in the video I linked to in my answer.

Comment: As far as the server side configuration goes they're the same **No applications need to be setup on your server**. For other secific integration with Laravel I couldn't say because I haven't used Amazon SQS (but I'm betting it shouldn't take more that the 5 minutes it takes to setup IronMQ).