# Using laravel queue fails to run on my shared hosting solution

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, queue

Trying to get queue to work on my shared host,

- I have set up a cron job to run 'php artisan queue:work' every minute.
- I am using the database driver
- The jobs get into the jobs table fine
- If I am using sync driver, it works on my shared host
  On my developer machine, it works both with Sync and Database driver.
- I dont fell [Laravel Queue: How to use on shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729445/laravel-queue-how-to-use-on-shared-hosting) provides a sufficient answer since I have cron possibility and therefore I would like to get it working with the database driver
- php is version 5.5 both from cli and web interface.

php artisan queue:work on my shared host (via cron) returns

```
[ErrorException] 
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

in my log file the following is written.

```
[2015-04-12 18:59:01] production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' in /home/a109/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php:287 Stack trace:
#0 /home/a109/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php(287): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/a109/vend...', 287, Array)
#1 /home/a109/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(823): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->hasParameterOption(Array)
#2 /home/a109/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->configureIO(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/a109/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(94): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/a109/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

at line 287 in vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Input/ArgvInput.php there is this function

```
  /**
 * Returns true if the raw parameters (not parsed) contain a value.
 *
 * This method is to be used to introspect the input parameters
 * before they have been validated. It must be used carefully.
 *
 * @param string|array $values The value(s) to look for in the raw parameters (can be an array)
 *
 * @return bool true if the value is contained in the raw parameters
 */
public function hasParameterOption($values)
{
    $values = (array) $values;

    foreach ($this->tokens as $token) {
        foreach ($values as $value) {
            if ($token === $value || 0 === strpos($token, $value.'=')) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

That is the sucker that fails.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

answered by Comyn in #laravel at freenode

I had to change the cron command to this:

```
php -d register_argc_argv=On artisan queue:work
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.7, there's a new queue command to stop working when empty:

`php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty`

As this is just for mostly emails or small few jobs, I put it on a cronjob to run every minute. This isn't really a solution for more than 20 jobs per minute I'd say, but works for my emails. This will run about 5 seconds every minute just to send emails, depending on how many emails.

#### Steps

1. Create new command: `$ php artisan make:command SendContactEmails`
2. In `SendContactEmails.php`, change: `protected $signature = 'emails:work';`
3. In the `handle()` method, add:

```
return $this->call('queue:work', [
    '--queue' => 'emails', // remove this if queue is default
    '--stop-when-empty' => null,
]);
```

4. In `app/Console/Kernal.php` file, add command to your list of commands:

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\SendContactEmails::class
];
```

5. Schedule your command every minute:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('emails:work')->everyMinute();
    // you can add ->withoutOverlapping(); if you think it won't finish in 1 minute
}
```

6. Update your cronjobs:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/project/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

---

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker)

> #### Processing All Queued Jobs & Then Exiting
>
> The `--stop-when-empty` option may be used to instruct the worker to process all jobs and then exit gracefully. This option can be useful when working Laravel queues within a Docker container if you wish to shutdown the container after the queue is empty:
>
> `php artisan queue:work --stop-when-empty`